# Minimal list of IntelliJ Idea plugins for Grails development

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea aims to be nearly everything for nearly everybody.  I just do Grails development.  What is the minimal setup needed for Grails development?  There is a long list of plugins installed and enabled by default.

The startup is slow as it scans the open project for a long time.  IntelliJ is really neat and clearly very powerful.  There are just most likely things I can do without which will speed things up a bit.

Comment: How slow is slow?

Comment: IMHO it does not matter how slow slow is, because the question is clear cut - the reasons don't really matter (yet if this already is so slow, that OP wants to optimize on that level, i'd say double your ram and get an ssd). It would help to add if this is Grails 2 or 3.  I'd *assume* that e.g. the later makes good use of e.g. the Gradle plugin.